# PHP Strings - method call inside string doesnt work as in manual

Tags: php

I am using the following as an example posted on the php manual that should let me use the return value of a method call inside a string...

```
echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}";

function getName()
{
    return "Bob";    
}
```

However I get an error: "`Notice: Undefined variable: Bob`"

This example is from the php manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Is the manual wrong or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Assign a value to $Bob and you'll be just fine...

Comment: If you're going to be building strings with method calls, I suggest assigning them to a variable or at least keeping the method call outside of the string itself.  It can get messy (as you can see...).

Answer (score 2):

You now have this:

```
"... {$getName()}"
```

This means that PHP is running the `getName()` function, gets `Bob` back and then reads:

```
"... {$Bob}"
```

Now, he is trying to get the variable `$Bob` (because variables are parsed in double quotes).

The solution is to use single quotes and put the function call outside the string:

```
'... {$'.getName().'}'
```

Or escape it:

```
"... \{\$getName()\}"
```

Comment: alternativately, there's variable functions. `$x = 'getName'; echo "{$x()}";`. Not that I recommend using them, but they do come in handy on occasion.

Comment: @MarcB is that working, to me it looks like it will try to call `x()` and then `$<return-value-of-x>`

Comment: nope. php will expand $x first, so it becomes "{getName()}", then execute the getName function. however, having a literal `echo "{getName()}"` will not work - it only works on variable expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this and it should do what you inteded

```
echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of ".getName();

function getName()
{
    return "Bob";    
}
```

Hope this is helping you

Comment: I know, but i am trying to understand php better from the ground up.  The manual says this should be possible and provides this example